# One method for several operations in Spring WS endpoints

Tags: java, spring, web-services, spring-ws

***Solution***: Write custom handling or move to integration framework like Camel or SI with dynamic type routing.

I have Spring WS endpoints marked with @Endpoint annotation. And i have a lot of methods for operations with identical code. Is there any way to create one method in endpoint for several specific operations using only Spring tools? May be i can put operations in array and spring will look for operations in that Array and call doOperatio method if operation was found there. Or something like this.

Typical method looks like this:

```
@PayloadRoot(localPart = Constants.OPERATION, namespace = Constants.NAMESPACE)
public void doOperation(@RequestPayload JAXBElement<SomeJAXBType> operationType) throws RemoteException {
   Processor.process(Constants.OPERATION, operationType);
}
```

Comment: Do all the operations  have the same request object ?

Comment: No. But actually mapping can be done in the array where key will be operation's name (localPart actually) and request object can be the value. Does spring support such things? Lets pretend so that request objects are the same. How this thing can be done through standard spring tools?